# Add Storage Feature to Cordova Project with CLI

Tags: android, cordova, storage, command-line-interface

I am using CLI for a Cordova Project. The App uses LocalStorage to store variables. On WP8 Platform this works out of the box. For Android it should work, too, but as far as I can see

```
<feature name="Storage">
     <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage" />
</feature>
```

has to be added to app/res/xml/config.xml.

The problem is, that this file is overwritten and prepared dynamically if running `cordova build android`. I have no idea how to use `org.apache.cordova.Storage` in my project and unsuccessfully tried the following:

- Adding the feature tag in the config.xml of the root folder.
- Adding a plugin tag in the config.xml of the root folder.
- Trying to install the plugin with `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.Storage`

Has anyone a suggestion how to use the Cordova Storage Plugin when working with CLI?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have a link to that plugin?  As far as I can tell it isn't in the plugin registry.  That means `plugin add` won't actually do anything

Comment: Exactly, a "not found" exception is thrown. Cordova documentation of an old version 3.0.0 advises to add feature tag to `app/res/xml/config.xml` as it should be built into Cordova (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) Anyway, as this file is overwritten, it doesn't work. An after prepare script that adds the feature tag could work but I got lost here.

Comment: Which version of Cordova are you running?  I couldn't find that plugin in the plugin registry, so the not found issue makes sense.  What is stopping you from running with window.localStorage or window.sessionStorage instead?